# Less important mixin

Tags: css, less

I've a mixing in order to generate some utilities class like that :

```
.margin(@name, @size){
  .@{name} {margin: (@size)px;}
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .xs-@{name} {margin: (@size)px;}
  }
}
```

It's working fine, but when I call 
`.margin(m-n, 0) !important;`

The css generated is :

```
.m-n {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .xs-m-n {
    margin: 0;
   }
}
```

But I would like to have :

```
.m-n {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .xs-m-n {
    margin: 0 !important;
   }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think the `!important` would get applied to properties within media queries using this method (atleast till v1.7.5) mate. For this particular case, a different (but round-about) method can be done.

Comment: Can you give me some information about your méthod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that works with a supplementary param

```
.margin(@name, @size, @important: false){
    .@{name} when (@important = false){
        margin: (@size)px; 
    }
    .@{name}   when (@important = true) {
        margin: (@size)px !important; 
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .xs-@{name} when (@important = false) {
            margin: (@size)px;
        }
        .xs-@{name}  when (@important = true) {
            margin: (@size)px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call `.margin(m-n, 0)` or `.margin(m-n, 0, true)`